# How do I parse a file sent with other data from a multipart HTML form?

Tags: python-2.7, multipartform-data, uwsgi

My server is uWSGI and Python. I send myself an image from a file upload on the web page. How do I parse that file on the server?
I was able to handle a CSV because it's just text and I sent it by itself, but I have no idea how to handle images, or if I send the text file with other data. I'll add sample POST data to clarify when I'm back at my computer.
Part of my problem is the previous developer did some weird things with parsing POST data, so instead of being able to let uWSGI turn it into usable data, I have to do that myself in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you were handeling url encoded data by doing read on `environ['wigs.imput']`, something like this.

```
try:
    request_body_size = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0))
except (ValueError):
    request_body_size = 0
request_body = environ['wsgi.input'].read(request_body_size)
dP = parse_qs(request_body)
```

For `multipart/form-data` data you need to use `cgi.FieldStorage`.

```
d = cgi.FieldStorage(environ=environ, fp=environ['wsgi.input'], keep_blank_values=True)
```

For Normal values in your form you can do

```
firstName = d.getvalue("firstName")
```

For the file you can get it by

```
file_data = d['imageFile'].file.read()
filename = d['imageFile'].filename
```

Comment: I made this the accepted answer because I'm assuming that's what you did to get the user photo upload to work.